# Finding if an item is available for booking in a given period search algorithm with SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, algorithm, search

Am asking for help with an algorithm for searching the availability of an item for a given period, this my table :

```
CREATE TABLE Emprunter
(
    idEmp int primary key identity,
    idClt int references Client,
    idMat int references Materiel,
    dateEmprunt date,
    dateRetour date, --this is a nullable 
    dureeEmprunt int,
    montantTotal money
)
```

The `dateRetour` column is nullable, the value will be inserted when the client return the item, so if an item has a dateRetour value the item is free and available.

Now this is what I came up with:

```
Create function IsMatrielDisponible
     (@idMat int, @dateD date, @dateF date)
returns bit
as
Begin
    Declare @Bool bit = 1

    if(Exists(select * 
              from Emprunter 
              where idMat = 2 and dateRetour is null
                and ((dateEmprunt >= @dateD or dateEmprunt <= @dateD) and dateEmprunt <= @dateF)))
        set @Bool = 0

    return @Bool
End

select  dbo.IsMatrielDisponible(1,'2018-03-05','2018-06-05')
```

but it is not working. I have a record with `id = 1` in the table with the `dateEmprunt = '2018-03-03'` and the dateRetour is null so the item lookup should return not available return 0, but the function returns 1

update - Table in designer:

[image]

the column is null as you can see.

for the behaver that i want is when i give the function a matériel (idMat) and a date depart (@dateD) and a date Return (@dateF) it should look for the item in the rent table (Emprunter) and if the item is available it should return 1, if not return 0,

Simple data:

[image]

for example if i looked for the item 3 is should be available because no one is renting it , but for item 1 is rented by another client because the dateRetour is null this means the client has not returned the item yet

```
select  dbo.IsMatrielDisponible(1,'2018-03-05','2018-06-05')
```

so by executing this it should return 0, i hope you get the idea

Comment: `(dateEmprunt >= @dateD or dateEmprunt <= @dateD )`   == `( 5 >= 1 or 5 <= 1)`  - just with dates -what is the point? emprunt is not nullable according to your DDL

Comment: I think there is a problem with this line:  dateEmprunt >= @ dateD or dateEmprunt <= @ dateD  you are doing an OR so your basically saying any date  I think maybe you want to change this to between, or change the OR to an and because as long as it is not null it is always going to be >=  OR <=  to your date

Comment: Also there is `idMat = 2`. So passing `1` for the `@idMat` has no effect.

Comment: 1 is the default return, there is no element fitting your `if` so its never set to 0. Typo - voting to close.

Comment: Please show sample data and expected results for that data. I do not see the `@idMat` function parameter used in your code. You do not mention what the `dateEmprunt` or `idMat` is, but you are using those in the code, so it seems those are significant for your problem, so please describe their role. (The `(dateEmprunt >= @dateD or dateEmprunt <= @dateD )` expression is always true for non-null values of `dateEmprunt` and `@dateD`.)

Answer (score 0):

I would consider rewriting this as an inline table valued function instead a scalar function. It is much better for performance and has a LOT more flexibility. I also removed a lot of extra code. Any value other 0 when being converted to a bit will be 1. So we can leverage COUNT for this quite easily. It can't return NULL and will return 1 if there are ANY rows that meet the query condition. I also removed the dateEmprunt stuff because it is not needed. There is no date that can be neither <= or >= to a given date. Maybe that should be a simple dateEmprunt IS NOT NULL but I don't know what you are trying to accomplish there.

```
Create function IsMatrielDisponible(@idMat int, @dateD date, @dateF date)
returns table as return

    select IsDisponible = convert(bit, count(*))
    from Emprunter 
    where idMat = @idMat
        and dateRetour is null
        --and ((dateEmprunt >= @dateD or dateEmprunt <= @dateD ) this is pointless as every value will return true from this
        and dateEmprunt <= @dateF

GO

select *
from dbo.IsMatrielDisponible(1,'2018-03-05','2018-06-05')
```